# Results Rows to String in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm very new to Powershell and need a very basic help.

I have a list of values as rows and want to make it as a string. Below is the list of items:

```
1011
1012
1013
1014
2014
```

I need to make this as `1011,1012,1013,1014,2014` and assign it to a variable.

Comment: https://www.midnightfreddie.com/powershell-split-and-join.html

Answer (score 2):

You don't give any code but you want a command that looks like this:

```
$result= $list -Join ", "
```

where $list is your items on separate lines.

Here is an article that gives examples of lots of use cases:

[midnightfreddie.com/powershell-split-and-join.html](http://midnightfreddie.com/powershell-split-and-join.html)

Comment: @ManojSivan - on stackoverflow it is best to up-vote and/or mark as correct an answer that helps.  The "thanks" are nice but the up-votes are better.